# 'Change Notifier Provider' isn't a function error message

Tags: flutter, flutter-change-notifier-provider

I am building a spelling app. This is the code that's giving me an error. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
void main() {
  runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Controller(), child: MyApp()));
}
```

The error message is

`'ChangeNotifierProvider' isn't a function.`

Comment: Please share the detailed error message

Comment: I have edited my post with the error message. @SanthoshRaja

Answer (score 0):

**you should use MultileProvider**

like this...

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

**and MyApp class uses MultipleProvider.**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<GetProvider>(create: (context) => GetProvider()),
      ],
      builder: (context, child) {
        return const MaterialApp(
          home: HomeScreen(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do Like This:

```
class Person with ChangeNotifier {
  Person({this.name, this.age});

  final String name;
  int age;

  void increaseAge() {
    this.age++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

// here, you can see that the [ChangeNotifierProvider]
// is "wired up" exactly like the vanilla [Provider]
void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => Person(name: "Yohan", age: 25),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {

  runApp( MyApp());

}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ThemeProvider(),
      builder: (context, _) {
        final provider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: provider.darkMode ? darkMode : lightMode,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```